# How to add custom header values to a spring kafka message?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to springboot kafka and I have created an example following this post.

https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-boot-example.html

I am currently using spring.kafka.version 1.1.6

I want to add custom headers, to the message so I can send certain properties in the header eg: fileName, fileId

I found out that you can set kafka metadata as headers and that's doesn't serve my purpose.

Is there anyway I can achieve this? I appreciate if you can share an example if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with version `1.3`, Spring Kafka is based on the Apache Kafka > `0.11`, which has introduced headers: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4208.

So, now you can use `KafkaTemplate` to send `ProducerRecord` with the `headers` populated.

Or you can send a `Message` and rely on the default `MessagingMessageConverter` who remaps headers from the message to the record via `KafkaHeaderMapper`.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#headers

Comment: Thank you. I am on spring.kafka.version 1.1.6 Does that mean I cannot use custom headers the way you have described? Is there any alternative that I can use?

Comment: Well, that's bad then. You can only *embed*  headers together with the `payload` into the `ProducerRecord.value`. Not clear though what stops you to upgrade all your environment to the state where everything is in a good shape already...

Comment: As long as your kafka broker is >= 0.11 you can use spring-kafka 1.3.x with boot 1.5.